# Get value from list returned by API

Tags: python, list, api

Im strugling to extract a certain value from a list returned by API call. This is the list (shorten version):

```
[{'account': 231584,'simpleCost': 0.0, 'simpleValue': 0.0, 'avgEntryPrice': 0.0, ...}]
```

and It is returned by:

```
client.Position.Position_get(filter=json.dumps({'symbol': 'XBTUSD'})).result()
```

I wish to get 'avgEntryPrice' extracted as a variable, thanks in advance guys!

Comment: Are you getting multiple dictionaries in your list? Do you want to get a list of `avgEntryPrice`?

Answer (score 2):

You would reach the value like this:

```py
list = [{'account': 231584,'simpleCost': 0.0, 'simpleValue': 0.0, 'avgEntryPrice': 0.0, ...}]
list[0]["avgEntryPrice"]
```

Because list only has the dictionary as its item. So you need to access the first item of list and then access the desired value with your key from that dictionary.

If you have multiple dictionaries you could do it like so:

```py
list = [{'account': 231584,'simpleCost': 0.0, 'simpleValue': 0.0, 'avgEntryPrice': 0.0}, {'account': 231584,'simpleCost': 0.0, 'simpleValue': 0.0, 'avgEntryPrice': 0.0}, {'account': 231584,'simpleCost': 0.0, 'simpleValue': 0.0, 'avgEntryPrice': 0.0}, {'account': 231584,'simpleCost': 0.0, 'simpleValue': 0.0, 'avgEntryPrice': 0.0}]
avgEntryPrices = [item["avgEntryPrice"] for item in list]
```

And this will return **avgEntryPrice** of each dictionary in your list.

Comment: returns
    
    KeyError: 'avgEntryPrice' unfortunelty :/

Comment: With the provided example data it was working. Can you check if your example data and the data returned from the api is matching? Also does every dict has **avgEntryPrice** key in them?